# how to draw a line on google maps on touchevent in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to draw a line on the Google maps between two points which i have touched, for example if i touch two points p0,p1 then a line should be drawn between these two points on the map

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

- Create a class extending `Overlay`
- Override `ontouch()` and save the geopoints taped
- Override `onDraw()` to convert geopoints above to screen
  coordinates using `Projection()` and use `canvas.drawLine()` to draw 
  a line between both points

good luck.